# Sort by the mode in an Array in Objective-C iPhone

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsarray, mode

If I have an NSArray with some values in them. Is there a way using descriptors to sort it by the most frequent number in the array first and the least frequent number at the end,

```
Array has(
"3",
"2",
"1",
"3",
"3",
"7",
)
```

to

```
Array has(
"3",
"3",
"3",
"1",
"2",
"7",
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@interface NSArray (Ext)
-(NSArray*) sortByMostFrequent ;
@end



@implementation NSArray (Ext)
-(NSArray*) sortByMostFrequent {
    NSMutableDictionary* frequencyDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (id obj in self) {
        int frequency = [[frequencyDict valueForKey:obj] intValue];
        [frequencyDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:frequency+1] forKey:obj];
    }
    NSMutableArray* ary = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.count];
    for (id obj in self) {
        [ary addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        obj, @"Object",
                        [frequencyDict valueForKey:obj], @"Frequency",
                        nil]];
    }
    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Frequency" ascending:NO];
    [ary sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    return [ary valueForKey:@"Object"];
}
@end



/// example
NSArray* ary = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3", @"2", @"1", @"3", @"3", @"7", nil];
NSLog(@"ary %@", [ary sortByMostFrequent]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without some additional data structures.

All the NSArray sorting operations (sortUsingDescriptors:, sortedArrayUsingSelector:, etc.) assume that you can look at two elements "a" and "b" and determine if "a < b" without looking at any other elements in the NSArray.

One solution would be to create a new Array whose member objects contain both the value and the frequency count (use an NSDictionary to efficiently count how many rows there are for each value). For example:

```
Array( // {value, frequency}
{3,3},
{2,1},
{1,1},
{3,3},
{3,3},
{7,1}
)
```

Then it's easy to use a descriptor to sort that array by frequency.